# How to copy the files that are missing in the simulator's bundle?

Tags: ios, xcode, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

In .app bundle I have the `ti.main.js` file but when I run the simulator I am not able to find this file in below location:

> /Users/MyLaptop/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E86C2B70-7367-4860-A3AC-FD4B44F21269/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A763F4AF-BFBD-471B-966B-9069DBF96E78/MyTitaniumMobileApp.app

I get the following error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “ti.main.js” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."

Can any one please help me understanding what’s going wrong here? I am not able to figure out how to get the `ti.main.js` file in the above mentioned directory when I run the app from the Xcode to iPhone 7 simulator.

Comment: Did you dragged and drop your `ti.main.js` file in your project navigator and selected `Copy files if needed`?

Comment: no. How to do that? In the project navigator i don't see this ti.main.js as its hidden inside the .app file. inside Product folder